# MongoDB script creates an empty object when it finds a null object instead of ignoring it, how can I fix this?

Tags: mongodb, if-statement, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a large script, the following section is the relevant part, but if people prefer I can post the whole script on request.
The script iterates through a list, looking for a field called `colour` and renames it `color`.

```
{
    serviceAgreementRefList: {
      $map : {
        input: "$$this.relatedJson.serviceAgreementRefList",
        in: {

           $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
               {
                  $cond: [
                     {                                                                              
                       $ne: [                                                                                          
                          "$$this.situation",                                                                                         
                          undefined
                          ]
                     },
                                                                                                                                                                           
                     "situation": {
                                                                                            
                        $mergeObjects: [
                           "$$this.situation",
                           {
                             color: "$$this.situation.colour",
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                 },
                {},
              ]
             }
            ]
           }
          }

        }
   }
```

It works as expected for the most part, however, if the object `situation` exists but is `null` then the script creates an empty `situation` object.
I would like any null `situation` objects to remain null.

How can I achieve that?

I thought I could add an `$or` function to the `$cond`, but of course that doesn't worse and in fact makes the problem worse.
Can I use an `$in` function, containing two `$ne` functions, one for `undefined` and one for `null`?
I would imagine I can, but I can't get the syntax right.

Comment: use https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/ in the condition

Comment: As in, use `$type` in `$ne` and test for `$$this.situation` != "missing" ?

Comment: I can't get that to work

Comment: `$type` works differently for a query vs an aggregation,  so I don't think it'll work here.

Comment: I gave the link to the aggregation $type, and the page contains examples. You need `$eq: [ {$type: "$$this.situation"}, "object"]` .  $type of no-situation will be "missing" and of null-situation will be "null".

Comment: Can you try this approach:
``$mergeObjects: [
            "$$this",
            {
              "situation":{
                $cond:[
                  {$eq:['$$this.situation', null]},null,{ $mergeObjects: ["$$this.situation",{color: "$$this.situation.colour",}]}]}},{},]``

Comment: @AlexBlex OK, thank you! I get it. Care to write an answer I can accept?

Comment: Glad it helped. May I ask you to make the writeup to contribute back to the community. I find these questions appearing quite often, likely because loosely typed nature of javascript is being confused with strict BSON typing.

Comment: Indeed I can. You've saved me a tonne of time :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution here is to use the `$eq` function instead of `$ne` and compare the type of the field to what we're expecting it to be.
If the type matches what we expect then the field name will be modified, if it doesn't, then nothing will be changed.
this is what the `$cond` function should look like:

```
          $cond: [
             {                                                                              
               $eq: [                                                                                          
                  { $type: "$$this.situation" },                                                                                         
                  "object"
                  ]
             },
             { <code to execute if true> },
             { <code to execute if false> }
          ]
```

if `situation` is populated then `$type` will return `"object"`, if it is `null` then `$type` will return `"null"` and if it does not exist `$type` will return `"missing"`.

Answer (score 1):

In Node, using Mongoose I solved it using this.

Define a default value in the object/array definition in yous schema

default:()=> undefined

This will ignore the object or array when it comes empty in your object. It will just not create it instead of creating an object with null values

For example, within a field called "operation" definition which is an array, I defined the element like this.

```
operations:{
    type:[operation],
    required:false,
    default:()=> undefined
}
```